# react useState only update new values in array

Tags: reactjs

Hi I'm trying to get the height of all the items and save it as an array like this [123,456,789]
but it just save as [123],[456],[789]
so tried to add heightV in the array. like this

```
  const elRef = React.useCallback(node => {
  ...code
  }, [heightV]);
```

but it makes an stack error and show it like this [123,123,123]
so is there's any way that I can update state old values and new value in one array?

```
  const [heightV, setHeight]: any = React.useState([]);
  const elRef = React.useCallback(node => {
    if (node !== null) {
      const height = node.clientHeight;
      setHeight((heightV: any) => [...heightV, height]);
    }
  }, []);
```

in component

```
<div ref={elref}>some dynamic items here</div>
```

Comment: What's inside `node.clientHeight`?

Comment: @EmanueleScarabattoli it just same as ref.current.clientHeight